# (C#) Unable to transfer order state using Session variable in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I have a table of Categories. The table can be sorted ascending/descending by clicking the "Name" AJAX anchor on top. The problem is that I can't transfer the current asc/desc state from the view to the controller. The idea is that whenever the user clicks that anchor, the sort type changes. Here is my code:

The **controller**:

```
public ActionResult Show(string sortBy)
{
    CategoryDao categoryDao = new CategoryDao();
    var categories = categoryDao.Read().Cast<Category>().ToList();

    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Session["SortType"] = "nameAsc";

        return this.View(categories);
    }
    else
    {
        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case "nameAsc":
                categories = categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
                Session["SortType"] = "nameDesc";
                break;
            case "nameDesc":
                categories = categories.OrderByDescending(c => c.Name).ToList();
                Session["SortType"] = "nameAsc";
                break;
            case "productCountAsc":
                // TODO
                break;
            case "productCountDesc":
                // TODO
                break;
        }

        return PartialView("_TableBody", categories);
    }
}
```

And the **view**(part of it):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Name", "Show", "Category", new { sortBy = Session["SortType"].ToString() },
         new AjaxOptions
         {
             HttpMethod = "GET",
             UpdateTargetId = "table-body",
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
         })
```

I tried debugging it and the Session variable keeps its "nameAsc" value on click.. The logic is fine as far as I am concerned. So if you can point out the wrong things in the code and proper fix I would be grateful!

Comment: Where do you change the `sortBy` value?  When you step through this in the debugger, where is the value being set to what you expect?

Comment: When the ActionLink is being clicked sortBy should get the value of the Session var... @David

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with how an `ActionLink` works in detail, but does the link *itself* re-render from server-side code?  I wouldn't think it does.  You can debug to confirm this, of course.  But I suspect you're only setting that value on the link *once* when the page loads and then never changing it.

Comment: @David: The link not being refreshed seems likely. I would assume that this link is in the header of the table and from the looks of the code that link only updates the table body, leaving the link in the header completely unchanged by the clicking.

Comment: No, it does not.. Or rather it changes it to "nameDesc" as should but when it returns to the view it passes back "nameAsc" as paramater from the ActionLink..@Chris

Comment: @Chris correct about the body update

Comment: @Toshkuuu: Take a closer look at what you describe as "when it returns to the view".  If nothing is updating that link then that link is going to have the same value it originally had when the page loaded.  So every click will send the same value to the server.  It doesn't matter what is stored in session if nothing ever *reads* from session.

Comment: @David But what about the "new { sortBy = Session["SortType"].ToString()" parameter?

Comment: @Toshkuuu: That sets the value *when the page loads*.  I highly doubt it's re-rendering that link each time the AJAX request is made.  (You can confirm this by debugging, of course.  Take a look at the AJAX requests/responses in your browser's tools, inspect the element and see if it changes, etc.)  Once the page has loaded, the server-side code is *done*.  It doesn't run again.

Comment: @Toshkuuu: is that action link in `_TableBody` or `Show` view? I'm guessing it is in the latter so the code you just quoted is only evaluated once, the first time that the `Show` view is processed. From there on it is only evaluating the `_TableBody` view and so isn't recreating that link.

Comment: @David Thanks, now I understood it. I should read more about AJAX i suppose. But any suggestions on a fix or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a hidden element to hold what you are ordering by, and update it via JavaScript when they click on a column header...